# Xamarin Android Google Plus SignIn

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, google-plus

I learning Xamarin Android, and i want to implement Google SignIn... But i'm not to be able to do that. I just need to use Client ID? i catch some examples in Internet but nothing works... Can someone give a example? or step by step how i can do this in Xamarin?

Thank you!

My Code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Common;
using System;
using Android.Gms.Plus;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Gms.Plus.Model.People;

namespace LoginGoogle
{
    [Activity(Label = "LoginGoogle", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener

{
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private SignInButton btnGooglePlus;
    private ConnectionResult connectionResult;
    private bool intentProgress;
    private bool signInClick;
    private bool infoPopulated;

    private TextView lblName;
    private TextView lblTagLine;
    private TextView lblBraggingRights;
    private TextView lblGender;
    private TextView lblRelationship;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        btnGooglePlus = FindViewById<SignInButton>(Resource.Id.btnGooglePlus);

        btnGooglePlus.Click += btnGooglePlus_Click;

        lblName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblName);
        lblTagLine = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblTagLine);
        lblBraggingRights = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblBraggingRights);
        lblGender = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblGender);
        lblRelationship = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblRelationship);

        GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);
        builder.AddConnectionCallbacks(this);
        builder.AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this);
        builder.AddApi(PlusClass.API);
        builder.AddScope(PlusClass.ScopePlusProfile);
        builder.AddScope(PlusClass.ScopePlusLogin);
        //Build our GoogleApiClient
        googleApiClient = builder.Build();

    }

    void btnGooglePlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!googleApiClient.IsConnecting)
        {
            signInClick = true;
            resolveSigInError();
        }
    }

    private void resolveSigInError()
    {
        if (!googleApiClient.IsConnected)
        {
            //No need to resolve errors
            return;
        }

        if (connectionResult.HasResolution)
        {
            try
            {
                intentProgress = true;
                StartIntentSenderForResult(connectionResult.Resolution.IntentSender, 0, null,
                    0, 0, 0);
            } catch (Android.Content.IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
            {
                intentProgress = false;
                googleApiClient.Connect();
            }

        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, 
        [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == 0)
        {
            if(resultCode != Result.Ok)
            {
                signInClick = false;
            }

            intentProgress = false;
            if (googleApiClient.IsConnecting)
            {
                googleApiClient.Connect();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        googleApiClient.Connect();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
        if (googleApiClient.IsConnected)
        {
            googleApiClient.Disconnect();
        }

    }

    public void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        //Successful login
        signInClick = false;

        if (PlusClass.PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson(googleApiClient) != null)
        {
            IPerson plusUser = PlusClass.PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson(googleApiClient);

            if (plusUser.HasDisplayName)
            {
                lblName.Text += plusUser.DisplayName;
            }

            if (plusUser.HasTagline)
            {
                lblTagLine.Text += plusUser.Tagline;
            }

            if (plusUser.HasBraggingRights)
            {
                lblBraggingRights.Text += plusUser.BraggingRights;
            }

            {
                switch (plusUser.RelationshipStatus)
                {
                    case 0:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "Single";
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "In a relationship";
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "Engaged";
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "Married";
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "It's complicated";
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "In an open relationship";
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "Widowed";
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "In a domestic partnership";
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "In a civil union";
                        break;

                    default:
                        lblRelationship.Text += "Unknown";
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (plusUser.HasGender)
            {
                switch (plusUser.Gender)
                {
                    case 0:
                        lblGender.Text += "Male";
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        lblGender.Text += "Female";
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        lblGender.Text += "Other";
                        break;

                    default:
                        lblGender.Text += "Unknown";
                        break;
                }

                infoPopulated = true;
            }
        }



    }

    public void OnConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
    {
        if (intentProgress)
        {
            //Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user 
            //clicks 'sign in'
            connectionResult = result;

            if (signInClick)
            {
                //The user has already clicked 'signin' so we attempt  to resolve all
                //errors until the user is signed in
                resolveSigInError();
            }

        } 


    }
}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [xamarin sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/SigninQuickstart/) for google sign in. In this sample you do not need  Client ID. For more google sign in information please check the google development [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

> I catch some examples in Internet but nothing works...

I think you may not authorized the app.

**Download the sample and make sure you've authorized the app in the Google Developers Console before use.**

> Authorized the app

1. Open the [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In).
2. Create your project name(whatever you write) and add the package name for it. In this sample the package name is `com.xamarin.signinquickstart`.
3. Get your SHA-1 please refer to this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/).
4. Build and deploy the demo app and sign in with google account.

Screen shot:

[image]

> But i'm not to be able to do that. I just need to use Client ID?

**How to use the Client ID login on**

According to google [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in). I think you can try to login with client id by:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new      GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
            .RequestIdToken("YOUR_CLIENT_ID")
            .RequestEmail()
            .Build();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder (this)
    .EnableAutoManage(mLoginFragment, failedHandler)
    .AddApi (Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
    .Build ()
```

Comment: There is also a video tutorial that can help you - [Xamarin Android Tutorial 36 Google+ Sign In Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wH-g59JfFY) and [Xamarin Android Tutorial 37 Google+ Sign in Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKoXQTFCWuE). Hope this helps.